# Indexing 1-D array using list of arrays with varying lengths

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, indexing, slice

Example of what I want to do:

```
import numpy as np

values = np.array([7, 7, 5, 2, 3, 9])
indices = np.array([
    np.array([3,5]), 
    np.array([4]),
    np.array([1,2,3])
    ])

>>> values[indices]
array([
    array([2,9]), 
    array([3]),
    array([7,5,2]),
    ])
```

Is it possible to achieve this using vectorization?
Right now I'm doing it with a for loop, but it can get slow.

Thanks!

Comment: Typically what's the length of `indices` and how many elements would you have in each of the arrays in it?

Comment: `len(values) == len(indices)` , and the length of each of the subarrays inside `indices` can vary from `1` to `len(values)`

Comment: Typically, what are those parameter values like? To get a sense of the dataset sizes with your actual use case.

Comment: The dataset size can be in the millions.

Comment: And typical length of the arrays in `indices`?

Comment: All the subarrays in the `indices` array have random length between `1` and `len(values)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We could concatenate the indices, index into `values` with those and finally split back -

```
idx = np.concatenate(indices)
all_out = values[idx]
lens = list(map(len,indices))
ssidx = np.r_[0,lens].cumsum()
out = [all_out[i:j] for (i,j) in zip(ssidx[:-1],ssidx[1:])]
```

For completeness, here's the straight-forward indexing based version -

```
[values[i] for i in indices]
```

So, with the proposed method we are making use of slicing and hence reducing per-iteration workload. As such, alongwith the step to get `idx` that needs concatenation of all indices in the proposed one, it makes sense for the case with small indexing arrays in `indices`.

Comment: Cool! Your method is about 15x faster than when I use for loop. Thank you you are a life saver :)))